# Using Zsh and QPDF to decrypt multiple PDFs

Tags: bash, for-loop, zsh, qpdf

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59688271/7577919 I was able to decrpypt multiple PDFs in place using this bash script:

```
temp=`ls`; 
for each in $temp;
do qpdf --decrypt --replace-input $each;  
done
```

However, I had initially attempted to do this in Zsh (as it's encouraged in MacOS 10.15 Catalina), but was unable. It gave an error of `output: File name too long`

What is the difference between the `for` loops in Bash and Zsh and how would I go about writing a proper Zsh script?

Comment: Will `for i in *; do qpdf --decrypt --replace-input "$i"; done` work? (Watch out for the quotes)

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Why? and why does it not need the ```temp=`ls` ```?

Comment: @dibery : If we are picky, your solution is not exactly equivalent. In the case of a directory without files, your solution would give an error message and set`each` do a single asterisk, while `ls` would expand to a null string.

Comment: @CTHall I guess there are some spaces in the filenames. You can debug it with issuing `set -x` before your script to see which file is the cause of this error. The asterisk expands to all files in that directory (if there is any file).

Comment: @user1934428 `zsh` does not treat an unmatched pattern as a literal string by default; it raises an error. Both `bash` and `zsh` can be configured to treat an unmatched pattern as an empty sequence (*not* a literal empty string), so that the loop would simply not be entered.

Comment: @chepner : Correct. That's why I had used the `(N)` qualifier in my answer for zsh. I should have mentioned this in my comment.

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah, I missed that you had an answer already before I commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the for-loop, but in the way variables are expanded. Consider this program:

```
x='a b'
for v in $x
do
  echo $v
done
```

In bash, $x would word-split into 2 arguments, and hence the loop would be executed twice, once for `a` and once for `b`. In zsh, $x would not undergo word-splitting and the loop would be executed once, for the valud `a b`. This difference is everywhere when you expand a parameter.

In your case, the loop is executed once, `each` holding the complete output of the `ls` statement.

Of course in your case, it would be simpler in zsh to write the loop as

```
for each in *(N)
```

but if you really need a variable, I would use an array:

```
temp=(*(N))
```

The `N`-flag after the wildcard takes care that you get an empty string instead of an error message, if there are no files.

If you also want to catch the dot-files (similar to what a `ls -A` would do), use `(ND)` instead.

Comment: I had a folder with just pdfs in it, but what if I had a folder with mixed files and just needed the pdfs? In bash I could set ` temp=`ls *.pdf` `but how would I do it in Zsh?

Comment: I don't see why you want to have a `temp` variable for your concrete, simple case, but if you do, it's simple: `temp=( *.pdf(N) )`. In bash, you would do a `temp=( *.pdf )`. Don't forget that when using an array, you would loop over it with `for f in ${temp[@]}` in zsh and with `for f in "${temp[@]}"` in bash.

Comment: To focussed on the original post I suppose. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since [parsing the result of ls is not encouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), it's probably not recommended to use `ls` to get the pdf filenames. Instead, you can use `find`:

```sh
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec qpdf --decrypt --replace-input "{}" \;
```

You can limit pdf in current directory by adding `-maxdepth 1` to `find`.